# How to make React app preview on mobile?

Tags: reactjs, networking, create-react-app

I am a noob using `create-react-app` to create a App, `yarn start` start the server at `http://localhost:3000/`, I can't visit this url on my mobile.
How can I make some configs to preview the app on my mobile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer here for Windows. Run ipconfig and scroll down to the IPv4 that is under Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

 (if you are on a wireless service) because react only provides you the ethernet IPv4 ip, that your phone will not be able to connect to.

Answer (score 75):

First, remember you can open a mobile view in a desktop browser (at least in Chrome and Firefox). See [the article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) for more. It isn't a substitute of testing on a real mobile device but can help you  identify more obvious issues.

Second, you need to use the IP address of your computer in your local network (assuming your mobile device is on the same network as your desktop). On Linux and Mac you can check your IP with `ifconfig` or using `ipconfig` on Windows. `localhost` always refers to the current machine, i.e. `localhost` on your desktop points to your desktop and on your mobile device it points to your mobile device. That's why you can't access it - the app runs on your desktop not mobile.

Once you know the IP address of your computer you need to replace `localhost` with it. In my case the IP is 192.168.1.10 so I use the following address to access my app:

```
http://192.168.1.10:3000/
```

Answer (score 46):

All answers are correct, except two points that are forgotten:

1. your network must be Private: on windows10, click on the wifi icon, then click on the network name, you'll see **properties** option, click on it, then on the **network profile** section, set it to **Private**
2. you might not be able to connect through the ip that `npm run start` writes in the cmd, try your other ip addresses too. as other friends mentioned, open cmd, type in: `ipconfig` and press Enter, then you'll see 3 parts that all have one line with: **IPv4 Address**, try all these ip addresses with the port number of your react application, i hope it helps

Comment: none of the answers worked. only after setting network to **Private** on windows 10 did it work. this answer is underappreciated for windows 10 users.

Comment: This is the answer that I have been looking for 

Answer (score 19):

If you want to test it on an actual device (That is what is recommended) you should ensure that you mobile phone is connected to the same network as you computer is and then when you run

```
yarn start
npm run start
```

You should see something like this:

```
On Your Network:  http://172.xx.xx.xxx:3000/
```

Just put that IP address in your mobile browser and test your web application

Comment: Note that you cannot have any errors or warnings on the `npm start`. I had unused variable warnings, in which case it doesn't show the `On Your Network`

Answer (score 10):

1. Type in cmd (windows): `ipconfig`
2. Look for IP address IPV4: [image: screenshot]
3. Type in URL search bar of your browser (example): `192.168.1.4:3000`
   3000 is the port number that your react app is running on:
   [image: screenshot2]

4. Make sure that your mobile browser (Chrome is preferred) is on the latest update, my react app didn't load up for me because chrome wasn't updated.

Answer (score 9):

This post is full of very useful information, However, i am also adding some of the points which have been left out, especially for a react app.

**If you are using create-react-app**

In this case when you start your react-app, it will show the url on which your can access the app on your device as shown in image below.
[image]

**If your are not using create-react-app(possibly webpack)**

1. Run your react-app server(webpack-dev-server for webpack).
2. Get your local ip using this command `ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}'`, you can get your ip in windows using `ipconfig` as ipv4 address.
3. Now simply put `http://<local-ip>:<port-number>` something like `http://192.168.1.106:3000` in your mobile browser and bam its there.

**Note** : above measures only works if both your mobile and server machine are connected to same network.

Answer (score 8):

1. Type ipconfig in your cmd...
2. See your public ip
3. Type that public IP in your mobile web browser with Port no.
   E.g: 192.168.0.175:3000/your_route
4. Enjoy( just make sure you are connected to same wifi )

Answer (score 6):

For windows:

1. Find your public IP using **ipconfig** in cmd. Find IPv4 address under **Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi**. Make sure your phone and pc are in the same LAN (connect to the same Wifi). Use `http://your_ip:3000` to preview your react app.
2. Tips: You must use **https** protocol to test the GPS service of your phone. For my case, I deployed it on Heroku to test the features using GPS.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac os Catalina you can find your local Ip in the terminal like so:

```
ifconfig
```

Under `(en0)` from the list, check the address that comes after `inet`

Answer (score 5):

```
Step 1:  First your system and Mobile should be on same WiFi network.
Step 2:  Run your React Application with   "npm start HOST=0.0.0.0" instead of "npm start"
Step 3:  Open your another terminal and get the your system IP address. for that you need to run "ifconfig" command in your terminal.
Step 4:  Open your mobile browser, and type "192.168.225.99:3000"  in your address bar.This is for Linux Users. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the answers about finding out what your IP address is, you should notice that your firewall might be interfering. If on Linux, you can disable it e.g.

`sudo ufw disable`

and to reenable it

`sudo ufw enable`

Answer (score 2):

Add a hostname to your `hosts` file that points to localhost. On Windows its usually located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, on Linux it lives at `/etc/hosts`, e.g.:

`127.0.0.1    my-app.dev`

Then setup a proxy server on your machine and configure your phone to use that as its proxy.

You should then be able to access your app via your phone's browser using the hostname specified above as URL.

Answer (score 1):

When you using create-react-app and then yarn start that link you a IP network

But that does not work for me, so:

1. Open a terminal then ipconfig
2. Find under your wifi adapter are you using IPv4 : youIpNumber
3. http://yourIpNumber:3000   //Note you must add the PORT

Answer (score 1):

In Some Cases the Mobile browser Refuses to Connect or Connection Timed-Out.
In such Cases follow these Simple Steps(Windows Users).

1. Go to **Windows Defender Firewall**
2. Click on **Advanced Settings**
3. Select **Inbound Rules**
4. Next, **New Rule**
5. Then, **Port** > **All Local Ports**(TCP Checked) > **Allow All Connections** > Give Any Name > Done!

[reactapp](/questions/tagged/reactapp) [windowsfirewall](/questions/tagged/windowsfirewall) [localhost](/questions/tagged/localhost)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just use a tunnel to your local port and replace "localhost:" with the tunnel url. The tunnel url is accessible from anywhere (as far as I know). I use ngrok for this. Ngrok documentation is pretty straightforward for getting started. https://ngrok.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

In windows, open command prompt and type

`ipconfig`

You will get a list where you can find the ip address. Copy the ip address and add :3000 to the end. Now you can use this link to preview the app in a phone.

In Ubuntu, open terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and type

`hostname -I`

It will give your ip address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `yarn dev`, use the flag `--host`.

```
yarn dev --host
```

This will expose the network and you can access it on the devices on the same network.

[image]